# Git cloned locally laravel project with XAMPP

Tags: git, apache, laravel, xampp, vhosts

I am starting with Laravel.

I cloned the project in my local machine and I am using XAMPP.

I created a virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost dev360.local:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/Users/Me/Git/dev360"
    ServerName dev360.local
    ErrorLog "logs/git.local-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/git.local-access.log" combined
  <Directory "C:/Users/Me/Git/dev360">
        Options All
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And I edited the host file like this:

```
# Git with XAMPP Windows
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       dev360.local
```

Now I can access to the root path but for accessing to the public folder I need the following url:
http://dev360.local/public_html

If I do that, the CSS files are not being loaded because they point to /media/... not to /public_html/media...

How can I fix that? Also, do I need to create a local environment in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change in 2 places: `C:/Users/Me/Git/dev360` to `C:/Users/Me/Git/dev360/public_html`. By the way it seems you changed default `public` to `public_html` - I mentioned about it just in case if it's different case.

Comment: This is actually working. That was a simple fix. Thanks a lot!